# Unique pointers to state + callbacks in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to bundle state in a struct together with callbacks that mutate the state.  It works fine when I use managed pointers:

```
struct StateAndCallbacks01 {
  state: @mut int,
  inc: @fn(),
  dec: @fn()
}

let state01: @mut int = @mut 0;
let inc01: @fn() = || {
  *state01 += 1;
};
let dec01: @fn() = || {
  *state01 -= 1;
};
let state_cbs_01 = @StateAndCallbacks01 {
  state: state01,
  inc: inc01,
  dec: dec01
};
(state_cbs_01.inc)();
println(fmt!("state: %d", *state_cbs_01.state));
(state_cbs_01.dec)();
println(fmt!("state: %d", *state_cbs_01.state));
```

Next, I want to send this structure to another task, and thus have to switch to unique pointers everywhere.  I cannot make that work: "error: obsolete syntax: const or mutable owned pointer"

```
struct StateAndCallbacks02 {
  state: ~mut int,
  inc: ~fn(),
  dec: ~fn()
}

let state02: ~mut int = ~mut 0;
let inc02: ~fn() = || {
  *state02 += 1;
};
let dec02: ~fn() = || {
  *state02 -= 1;
};
let state_cbs_02 = ~StateAndCallbacks02 {
  state: state02,
  inc: inc02,
  dec: dec02
};

let (port, chan): (Port<bool>, Chan<bool>) = stream();
do spawn {
  (state_cbs_02.inc)();
  println(fmt!("state: %d", *state_cbs_02.state));
  (state_cbs_02.dec)();
  println(fmt!("state: %d", *state_cbs_02.state));
  chan.send(true);
};
let result = port.recv();
println(fmt!("result: %s", result));
```

Any suggestions?  Any better ways to send callbacks across tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of keeping the functions as fields in the struct you can instead add methods to the struct.

```
struct Foo {
    data: int
}

impl Foo {
    fn inc(&mut self) {
        self.data += 1;
    }
}
```

The `impl` syntax lets you define methods on the struct. Which you can later call:

```
let mut my_foo = Foo { data: 0 };
my_foo.inc();
```

You have to declare `my_foo` as mutable since the `inc` method needs to take a mutable reference to it.

The reason for the obsolete syntax error is because doing `~mut 0` is deprecated since mutability is determined by who 'owns' the object. What you'd have to do instead is `let mut foo = ~0`. The variable `foo` is the 'owner' and thus is where you declare the mutability. `@-`pointers are special in that they don't inherit mutability and are managed by a task local GC. (Sections 8 & 9 of the [Rust tutorial](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/tutorial.html) better explain this)

So with all that put together, you could write your original code like so:

```
struct State {
    data: int 
}

impl State {
    fn inc(&mut self) {
        self.data += 1;
    }   

    fn dec(&mut self) {
        self.data -= 1;
    }   
}

fn main() {

    let state = State {
        data: 0
    };  

    let (port, chan) = stream();

    do spawn {

        let mut state = state;

        state.inc();
        println(fmt!("State: %d", state.data));
        state.dec();
        println(fmt!("State: %d", state.data));

        chan.send(true);
    };  

    let result = port.recv();
    println(fmt!("Result: %?", result));

}
```

Comment: The plain `impl` solution only works if there is only one possible value of `inc` and `dec`; if these functions change depending on the data, using either traits or just using the owned closures in the structs (without the `mut` in `~mut`) would be better.

Comment: I neglected to mention, but I really needed multiple implementations of inc/dec.  This was a simplified version of a problem I was having with XML SAX event handlers, and instead of inc/dec I would have start_element/end_element/text.  Attempted to do something similar with a trait added.

let state = ~State { ... gave an "error: moving out of captured outer variable in a heap closure".  Doing exactly what you did worked.  I really don't get it why an owned pointer cannot be passed into the task, but a stack reference works.